# List of context

Tags: vba, excel

The following code makes a list of sheets:

```
Sub Listofcontent()

Dim objSheet As Worksheet
Dim intRow   As Integer
Dim strCol   As Integer
Dim GCell As Range

SearchText = "Content"
Set GCell = Worksheets("Front page").Cells.Find(SearchText).Offset(2, 0)

GCell.End(xlDown).ClearContents

intRow = GCell.Row
strCol = GCell.Column

For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Front page").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Front page").Cells(intRow, strCol), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "'" & objSheet.name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=objSheet.name
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("0.0 Forside").Cells(intRow, strCol).Font
            .name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Normal"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
    intRow = intRow + 1
Next objSheet
End Sub
```

It works now. Thanks. However, I want it to run whenever a sheet is added, deleted, renamed, moved, copied. I added this to the workbook code pane:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Listofcontent
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Listofcontent
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it and on which line? Otherwise, what is happening now?

Comment: `For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count` should probably be `For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.workSheets` but you are doing nothing to avoid adding the 'Front page' worksheet.

Comment: ^^Oh just saw when posting you had also written this

Comment: Ok. So you have changed the question..... and what is wrong with this version?

Comment: As you already found out there is a event for "add": `Workbook_NewSheet`. There are no events triggered after: delete, rename, move or copy so it is not possible to run code automatically after these actions.

Comment: Workbook_NewSheet runs the "Listofcontent" when a sheet is added. Since there are no events triggering after delete, rename, move or copy, I added the Workbook_SheetActivate, so whenever I enter a sheet, the "Listofcontent" is triggered. However, it does not seem to work...

Comment: "*does not seem to work*" is meaningless. Did you debug your code and go through it step-by-step with F8? does the event not trigger or does `Listofcontent` not run properly? Did you anywhere in your code disable events `Application.EnableEvents = False` and forget to enable them? This would prevent the event to be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
```

To

```
For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
```